# How to convert from a flattened 3D index to a set of coordinates?

Tags: computer-science

I have a flattened 3D array in row-major format with an index, $I$, defined as $I = x + y D_x + z D_x D_y$, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the indices and $D_x$, $D_y$, and $D_z$ are the dimensions of the 3D array. How can I obtain the original set of coordinates from the index $I$?

(This question has been asked a number of other places on StackExchange with no actual derivation of the solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with the standard definition of integer division: $a = qd +r$, where $a$ is the dividend, $q$ is the quotient, $d$ is the divisor, and $r$ is the remainder. From here, we define the integer division operator $div(a, d)=q$ and the modulo operator $mod(a, d) = r$.

Starting with our index,
$$I = x + y D_x + z D_x D_y$$

Rewriting to fit the division form above,
$$I = D_x (y + z D_y) + x$$

We can now solve for $x$:
$$mod(I, D_x) = x$$

Now for $y$ and $z$, we extract the inner expression:
$$div(I, D_x) = y + D_y z$$

But, this has the same form as the expresion for $x$. Thus,
$$mod(div(I, D_x), D_y) = y$$
$$div(div(I, D_x), D_y) = z$$

Note: this derivation extends quite easily to higher dimensions.